# Python: Parse ISO 8601 date and time from a string (using the standard modules)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to parse the date for entries given by SVN:

```
svn list --xml https://subversion:8765/svn/Foo/tags/
```

If I am not mistaken it is given using the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. An example is:

```
dateString = "2012-02-14T11:22:34.593750Z"
```

I am using Python 2.7 and am looking for the best way to process is using the standard modules only. I think I´ll parse it this way using a regular expression: `^---` is a match group and `A` indicates that I will assume that they are always there (which might be a weakness)

```
dateString = "2012-02-14T11:22:34.593750Z"
              ^--- ^- ^-A^- ^- ^--------A
                        |               |
                        |  I think it always gives the date
                        |  as UTC, which Z means in ISO 8601.
                        |
                 Just a separator
```

After parsing it I´ll simply create a datetime from it.

Is there a better way using Python 2.7 with only the standard modules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I translate a ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object)

Comment: It is possible, it depends on what has happened between Python 2.5 (which the other ones uses) and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for a regexp, use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I parsed it successfully using  `datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string_to_parse, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')`. I didn´t get it to parse the timezone (the Z) so I hard coded it as I think the output I´m parsing always will be using Z.