# Parse xsd:dateTime formatted string to python datetime

Tags: python, datetime, xsd, timezone

Given a string in [xsd:dateTime format](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77049.html) I want to create a python datetime object.
I especially need to be able to parse for example a string like this '2012-09-23T09:55:00', but also all other defined examples should be parsed correctly, and also use timezones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I translate a ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`datetime.datetime.strptime` class method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse these:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(xsdDateTime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Your example does *not* include a timezone however. If you really do need timezone support, best resort to the [`python-dateutil` module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse(xsdDateTime)
```

Comment: No module named parsing
edit: the modul is called parser not parsing
but it seems to work now

Comment: @MartinFlucka: Corrected, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

i would also recommend the python-dateutil package.
i am using version 2.7.3, that also has an isoparser.
however, the isoparser doesn't parse time only strings, and i've filled an issue.
use the parser module instead.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse(xsdDateTime)
```

hth,
alex