# Converting (YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM:SS) date time

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to convert a string like this `"29-Apr-2013-15:59:02"`
into something more usable.

The dashes can be easily replaced with spaces or other characters. This format would be ideal: `"YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss (20130429 15:59:02)"`.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I did not specifically see the answer in another post. But again, I'm ignorant so could have been looking at the solution and didn't know it. I've got this working, but I wouldn't consider it "pretty."

```
#29-Apr-2013-15:59:02

import sys, datetime, time

#inDate = sys.argv[1]
inDate = 29-Apr-2013-15:59:02

def getMonth(month):
    monthDict = {'Jan':'01','Feb':'02','Mar':'03','Apr':'04','May':'05','Jun':'06','Jul':'07','Aug':'08','Sep':'09','Oct':'10','Nov':'11','Dec':'12'}
    for k, v in monthDict.iteritems():
        if month == k:
            return v

day = inDate[:2]
#print day
month = inDate[3:6]
#print month
year = inDate[7:11]
#print year
time = inDate[-8:]
#print time

newDate = year+getMonth(month)+day
newDateTime = newDate+" "+time

print newDate
print newDateTime
```

Any thoughts on improving?

Comment: Have you read the [`strftime()` and `strptime()` behavior](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) documentation? there are examples there that should help you.

Comment: @Andbdrew -- Careful:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic

Comment: I would try adjusting how you are getting that date string if possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use [datetime.strptime()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the `inDate` string into a date object, use [datetime.strftime()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to output in whatever format you like:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> inDate = "29-Apr-2013-15:59:02"
>>> d = datetime.strptime(inDate, "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S")
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 29, 15, 59, 2)
>>> d.strftime("YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss (%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S)")
'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss (20130429 15:59:02)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you investigated dateutil?

http://labix.org/python-dateutil

I found a similar question to yours:
[How do I translate a ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object)

Comment: There's no need to use `dateutil` here, the standard `datetime` module is perfectly apt.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), in particular `strptime`.