# Python append hyphen to date output from an API

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pycharm

I am trying to download stock data using an api, and for the api to work I need to request the date in the YYYYMMDD format, however I would like it to output YYYY-MM-DD.

Currently I am using this code to request the data:

```
write(symbol, ";", exchange, ";", bar.date.replace(' ', '; '), ";", bar.open, ";", bar.high, ";", bar.low, ";", bar.close, ";", bar.volume)
```

Since the API gives me the output: "YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS", I have already used the command .replace(' ', '; '), so that it puts a semicolon behind the date output. Now i also would like to format the date output to YYYY-MM-DD, but I think because I am using the .replace i cannot seem to find a way to let this work myself.

Could anyone here help me out?

Comment: You should use Python's Datetime module for this (link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: You can use this as reference (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288609/1305461), and this portion of the documentation to help (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: String only (ugly): `s0 = "YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS"`,  `s1 = "".join([s0[:4], "-", s0[4:6], "-", s0[6:]])`, `print(s1)`.

Comment: The safest way is going to be to parse the output into a `datetime`, probably with `datetime.strptime`, and then either `strftime` or one of the convenience methods like `.isoformat()`.

Comment: I would follow @PeterDeGlopper advice on this OP. Makes your code more readable, and it's def. more proper. I posted resources for documentation above.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I went with N. Chauhan's answer since it made the most sence to me, but Pete's should work aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the string into a list of characters. Then insert hyphens at the desired indexes:

```
date = list(bar.date.replace(' ', ';'))
date.insert(4, '-')
date.insert(7, '-')  # not 6 as the first hyphen shifts them up
write(symbol, ";", exchange, ";",
      ''.join(date),
      ";", bar.open, ";", bar.high,
      ";", bar.low, ";", bar.close,
      ";", bar.volume)
```

This all assumes that the date format is always guaranteed to be in the same format.

Comment: Awesome man, I have been bugging myself for over an hour to figure this out. it worked great! Since I am a new user I don't think I can up your answer, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why other answers are suggesting regex when we have the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module for this. Use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert an arbitrary string to a datetime, and then convert back to a string with [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime). The format options are at the bottom of the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```
import datetime as dt

date = '20190522 20:00:24'
new_date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: No offense taken dude. You are anyway one of the my favorite SO users :D (Commenting here because the other post was deleted)

Answer (score 2):

No need of regular expressions or string replace. Just use the built in datetime module.

```
from datetime import datetime

bar.date.strftime(“%Y-%B-%d”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast way using `regex` :

```
import re
a='20180230;HHMMSS'
re.sub(r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*',r'\1-\2-\3',a)
```

Output:

```
'2018-02-30'
```

The code finds 4 numbers in a row, then two numbers in a row and then two other numbers in a row and puts a hiphen inbetween those three groups. Then, it ignores **anything** that comes after those three groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `import datetime from datetime`
`str(datetime.now()).replace(" ","-")[:10]`