# Get YYYY-DD-MM from YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date in the format `2012-01-01 06:00:00`. I want to get only the date in the format `2012-01-01`.

I've tried multiple links such as [Converting (YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM:SS) date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286991/converting-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-date-time)
But, I could not find the solution.

Comment: What format / object type is your date ? datetime.time object ?

Comment: I have an integer number and based on .apply(datetime.fromtimestamp) I have the date with hours and minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse. `str -> date`.

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "2012-01-01 06:00:00"
dt = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

2. Format. `date -> str`.

```
s_ymd = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Result:

```
>>> s_ymd
'2012-01-01'
```

Comment: Thanks. However, when I run this code I got this error: ''Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: Sounds like you're using `pandas`. Try asking a new question with that information included in it. I'm guessing what you want is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132282/datetime-to-string-with-series-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date is a string, the following works fine:

```
str = "2012-01-01 06:00:00"
print(str[:10])
```

The notation `[:10]` basically means "take first 10 characters of the string".