# Unserialize Python aware datetime

Tags: python, datetime, serialization, timezone, yaml

How do you unserialize a timezone-aware datetime object? PYYAML will automatically save them correctly in the ISO format, but drops the timezone info when loading. Using str(my_datetime_object) makes a correct ISO string, but the datetime module has no clean way to convert it back to a datetime object. (strftime has no ISO-compatible timezone format)

dateutil.parser.parse does something weird that's still not right:

```
In [113]: x
Out[113]: datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 15, 21, 58, 25, 866385, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Athens' EET+2:00:00 STD>)

In [114]: str(x)
Out[114]: '2014-02-15 21:58:25.866385+02:00'

In [115]: dateutil.parser.parse(str(x))
Out[115]: datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 15, 21, 58, 25, 866385, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))
```

Comment: It is a correct result. `7200 = 2 * 60 * 60 = hour_offset * 60*minutes/hour * 60*seconds/minute`. It can not know that you are in Athen since this is a string and the information is lost when it is not shown in the string. You will need an format that also allows the town.

Comment: What do you mean by "unserialize a timezone-aware datetime object"? Do you want to transform it into a known timezone or just output it as string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I translate a ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object)

Comment: Take a look at this question.  Many of the answers talk about handling timezone-aware objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object

Comment: User - that checks. If you write it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should serialize this to a datetime and a timezone. The timezone should be stored as the Timezone name, in this case `'Europe/Athens'`. What format you use for the datetime is less important, but I'd recommend serializing the datetime as a separate field from the timezone, and using UTC, and explicitly so. How this looks more explicitly is entirely dependent on how the rest of your seialization format looks.

For example:

```
{datetime: "2014-02-15 19:58:25.866385+00:00", timezone: "Europe/Athens"}
```

Comment: to get the timezone id, `x.tzinfo.zone` could be used with pytz timezones (such as in this case). If datetime is serialized as UTC time then `utc_aware.astimezone(tz)` could be called, to get an aware datetime object in `tz` timezone.