# GQL Query (python) to retrieve data using timestamp

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I have a table in **Google Datastore** that holds *n* values in *n* columns, and one of them is a `timestamp`.

The `timestamp` property is defined like this, inside the table class (Java):

```
@Persistent
private Date timestamp;
```

The table is like this:

```
    id    |    value    |            timestamp    
----------------------------------------------------------
     1    |    ABC      |    2014-02-02 21:07:40.822000   
     2    |    CDE      |    2014-02-02 22:07:40.000000   
     3    |    EFG      |       
     4    |    GHI      |    2014-02-02 21:07:40.822000   
     5    |    IJK      |       
     6    |    KLM      |    2014-01-02 21:07:40.822000
```

The `timestamp` column was added later to the table, so some rows have not the corresponding `timestamp` value.

I'm trying, using **Python Google App Engine** to build an api that returns the total number of rows that have a timestamp `>=` to some value.

For example:

```
-- This is just an example
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE timestamp >= '2014-02-02 21:07:40.822000'
```

I've made this class, in python:

```
import sys
...
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db

class myTable(db.Model):
    value = db.StringProperty()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime

class countHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, tablename, timestamp):

        table = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM " + tablename + " WHERE timestamp >= :1",  timestamp )
        recordsCount = 0

        for p in table:
            recordsCount += 1

         self.response.out.write("Records count for table " + tablename + ": " + str(recordsCount))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/count/(.*)/(.*)', countHandler)
], debug=True)
```

I've successfully deployed it and I'm able to call it, but for some reason I don't understand it's always saying

```
Records count for table myTable: 0
```

I'm struggling with the data type for the timestamp.. I think the issue is there.. any idea? which type should it be declared?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that timestamp is not a string ? It needs to be datetime in my knowledge.

Comment: @JimmyKane I've defined it as `Date` in the Java class, so it should be date.. I'll give it a try, python side, with `timestamp = db.StringProperty()` if this is what you mean

Comment: I think that you need to have timestamp in a datetime format. Just convert it to datetime and use that object for the query. Inform if it worked. I have some time to use it in my queries and atm I don't have the convenience to test.

Comment: @JimmyKane sorry to be boring, but you mean python or java side? (maybe in python there's some `datetime` different than `datetime.datetime`?)

Comment: no it's datetime.datetime (if you import datetime). What I mean is that I can see in the python side(where your problem is) that you use the timestamp as a string. I think you should convert that to datetime  object. Look here for help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object

Later if I have some time I will setup a test case for this.

Comment: @JimmyKane I thought that the parameterized query maintained the type.. I'll test your suggestion asap, thank you!

Comment: @JimmyKane your hint solved my problem, thank you. If you reply to the  original question, I'll accept your answer! thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem (as discussed in the comments as well) seems to be that you are passing a string (probably) to the GqlQuery parameters.

In order to filter your query by `datetime` you need to pass  a `datetime` object in to the query params. For that take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object) on how to convert that.

Small example:

```
# not sure how your timestamps are formatted but supposing they are strings
# of eg 2014-02-02 21:07:40.822000
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f" )

table = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM " + tablename + " WHERE timestamp >= :1",  timestamp)
```

Comment: Actually, I used the other example: `tmstmp = dateutil.parser.parse(timestamp)`. Note that, this way, I needed to download and import dateutil lib.

Comment: @BeNdErR Sure that will work as well. I am a bit more familiar the datetime module. Glad that it solved it.

Comment: probably your solution would have saved me the import of the new lib :)