# How to convert "Tue Feb 25 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)" to python datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime

I have some doubts in the dateformat `Tue Feb 25 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`.

- does `Tue Feb 25 2014 00:00:00` means `GMT` or `IST`
- Is it possible to convert this into python `datetime`.
- and also is it possible convert it into format `DD-MM-YY,HH:MM:SS` in GMT.

Here is what i tried to convert into `python datetime`::

but i got error,when i tried with `%z`:

```
>>> time_format="%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)"
>>> v="Tue Feb 25 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"
>>> mydate=datetime.strptime(v,time_format)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 317, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)'
```

But this works:

```
>>> time_format="%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT (%Z)"
>>> v="Tue Feb 25 2014 00:00:00 GMT (IST)"
>>> datetime.strptime(v,time_format)    
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 25, 0, 0)
```

**but still didn't understand anything about `TIMEZONE`**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I translate a ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object)

Comment: @MartijnPieters so what does `Tue Feb 25 2014 00:00:00` means? `GMT` or `IST`

Comment: IST. The offset is given *relative to* GMT. The Indian Standard Time timezone is 5 hours, 30 minutes east of Greenwich Main Time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but i got error,when i tried with `%z` which is mentioned in [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) documentation

Comment: I linked you to a duplicate; there are no timezone definitions in the standard Python library. Note that `%z` is also handled at the C level, which knows even less about Python and timezone support (although I heard Python 3.2 and up handle that case better).

Comment: @MartijnPieters so i want to use `python-dateutil`? does it worth it beacuse it needs to download a python library for just to parse.

Comment: The library gives you timezones *and* painless date/time string parsing. It works directly on your input. Yes, you want to use `python-dateutil`.

Comment: Are you trying to map IST to a *time zone aware `DateTime`*?  Make sure you understand "naive" vs "aware" as described [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).  Also, are you using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)?  If so, you probably want the `Asia/Kolkata` time zone.  If not, you can (in this special case) create a time zone with a fixed +0530 offset.  But don't try to apply that in the general case, since many time zones go through changes for daylight saving time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the system terminal

```
easy_install python-dateutil
```

In the python shell

```
from dateutil import parser as date_parser
print date_parser.parse("Tue Feb 25 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)")
```

Dateutil's parse can typically just parse anything you throw at it into a Python datetime.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way would be to try something like this, especially if you want to avoid using external libraries for example in Python 3.6.9 :

```
datetime.strptime(v,"%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z (IST)")
```