# Parse rfc3339 date strings in Python?

Tags: python, date, datetime-parsing, rfc3339

I have a datasets where all the dates have the following format:

```
2012-10-09T19:00:55Z
```

I'd like to be able to be able to use methods like `.weekday` on them. How do I convert them to the proper format in Python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object duplicate?

Answer (score 169):

You can use [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) (install with `python -m pip install python-dateutil`) to parse strings into datetime objects.

`dateutil.parser.parse` will attempt to guess the format of your string, if you know the exact format in advance then you can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) which you supply a format string to (see Brent Washburne's answer).

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

a = "2012-10-09T19:00:55Z"

b = parse(a)

print(b.weekday())
# 1 (equal to a Tuesday)
```

Comment: I don't know why I haven't heard of `dateutil.parser`. These are the little things that make Python awesome. `from somemodule import problemsolver && problemsolver.solvemyspecificproblem()`

Comment: @kraxor probably because it's not actually part of Python, rather a 3rd-part library. `git clone http://example.com/module/problemsolver problemsolver && cd problemsolver && python problemsolver.py myspecificproblem`

Comment: @Ffisegydd My mistake, I did 'pip install dateutil' rather than prepending with python-.

Comment: You need to indicate that thus us a third party lib

Comment: @kraxor Python is awesome because it the accepted answer on how to parse a date requires installing a 3rd party library? That seems somewhat less than awesome.

Comment: Little catch with `parse` is dates like this: `parse("12/11/2017 07:41:27")
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 11, 7, 41, 27)` asumes the first arg is the month
`parse("13/11/2017 07:41:27")
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 13, 7, 41, 27)` magically makes the first arg the day. All explainable just something you need to know.

Comment: @albertjan That gotcha is not ISO-8601 compliant, so it wouldn't be an issue here.  The ISO 8601 standard requires a descending arrangement of terms (whether Y-M-D, Y-M, Y-D, Y-W, etc). Though personally I'd prefer that it raise an exception unless some flag is set to automatically convert non-conforming dates.

Comment: To clarify @Paul's comment, the command to install dateutil with pip is `pip install python-dateutil`. The "python-" part is required!

Answer (score 94):

This has already been answered here: [How do I translate a ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/969285/584846)

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime( "2012-10-09T19:00:55Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" )
d.weekday()
```

Comment: This is suboptimal, since it requires the caller to provide format strings for the rather wide range of ISO 8601 variants (unless one likes ValueError if the seconds are omitted, e.g).  The dateutil parser, on the other hand, handles these much better.

Comment: @AlexNorth-Keys: How is this suboptimal?  The OP stated "I have a datasets where all the dates have the following format" and didn't mention any variants.  This answer is actually optimal because it doesn't require any external modules, it uses the built-in datetime module.  By using the exact format string (instead of having dateutil guess the format every time), the code performance is optimal.

Comment: I was thinking from a maintenance perspective (oops) - but you're right, the strptime method is faster, running in about 1/6th of the time the dateutil.parser approach does.

Comment: `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` produces a “naive” datetime. To produce an “aware” datetime (i.e., aware of the time zone): `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"`

Answer (score 10):

You should have a look at [`moment`](https://github.com/zachwill/moment) which is a python port of the excellent js lib [`momentjs`](http://momentjs.com/).

One advantage of it is the support of [`ISO 8601`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings formats, as well as a generic "% format" :

```
import moment
time_string='2012-10-09T19:00:55Z'

m = moment.date(time_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print m.format('YYYY-M-D H:M')
print m.weekday
```

Result:

```
2012-10-09 19:10
2
```