# strptime() with varying input data

Tags: python, datetime

Some stable genius before my time wrote their dates into the database as strings. Not only that, but the format varies too. I have at least

```
05.08.1993
```

and

```
31.08.1993 00:00:00
```

Now I want to convert those to datetime objects using strptime(), e.g.

```
my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_value, '%d.%m.%y')
```

So now I have to deal with the different formats. I can think of varous clumsy ways to do this, invlvong ugly cascades of ifs or trys. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: I would suggest using RegEx to determine which format you got at Hand. You could also try using `dateutil.parser.parse()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/23277356/3858121

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use **[python dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil)**

**Demo:**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

a = "05.08.1993"
b = "31.08.1993 00:00:00"

print(parse(a).strftime('%d.%m.%y'))
print(parse(b).strftime('%d.%m.%y'))
```

**Output:**

```
08.05.93
31.08.93
```

---

**Using Regex:**

```
import re
import datetime

a = "05.08.1993"
b = "31.08.1993 00:00:00"
d = re.search("\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}", a)
if d:
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(d.group(),'%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%d.%m.%y'))

d = re.search("\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}", b)
if d:
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(d.group(),'%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%d.%m.%y'))
```

**Output:**

```
05.08.93
31.08.93
```

Comment: Looks good. Unfortunately, that's not in the standard libray, so getting this installed here is going to take me days or even weeks.

Comment: @uwain12345 the regex should help then.

Answer (score 1):

[`dateutil.parser`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html):

> This module offers a generic date/time string parser which is able to parse most known formats to represent a date and/or time.
>
> This module attempts to be forgiving with regards to unlikely input formats, returning a datetime object even for dates which are ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2 datatypes you mentioned, it should be sufficient to harness slicing:

```
my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_value[:10], '%d.%m.%Y')
```

for a more robust approach, you can use generic date parsers, as other answers mention.

Answer (score 0):

If it are only 2 patterns, this can be done with `re`

```
dates = ('05.08.1993', '31.08.1993 00:00:00')
pattern = re.compile(r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
strp_pattern = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
strp_pattern_fallback = '%d.%m.%Y'

def parse_dates(dates):
    for date in dates:
        if pattern.match(date):
            yield datetime.datetime.strptime(date, strp_pattern)
        else:
            yield datetime.datetime.strptime(date, strp_pattern_fallback)

list(parse_dates(dates))
```

> ```
> [datetime.datetime(1993, 8, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1993, 8, 31, 0, 0)]
> ```