# AWS boto Get Snapshots in Time Period

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, snapshot

I'm using AWS and pulling snapshots using boto ("The Python interface to Amazon Web Services"). I'm pulling all snapshots using `conn.get_all_snapshots()`, but I only want to retrieve the necessary data. I'm using a calendar to view the snapshots, so it would be very helpful if I could only pull the snapshots within the current month I'm viewing.

Is there a restriction (maybe a filter) I can put on the `conn.get_all_snapshots()` to only retrieve the snapshots within the month?

Here are boto docs if necessary: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this.  The EC2 API allows you to filter results based on snapshot ID's or by various filters such as `status` or `progress`.  There is even a filter for `create-time` but unfortunately there is no way to specify a range of times and have it return everything in between.  And there is no way to use `<` or `>` operators in the filter query.

Comment: This seems very necessary, especially because I don't want to save thousands of snapshots in the backend. Is there any solution?

Comment: Well, you could always store the timestamps and snapshot IDs in DynamoDB or some other database and query that to find the snapshot IDs you want to retrieve.

Comment: Ok. Think I'll shy away from that. Thanks for the response anyways. BTW boto rocks in every other way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the snapshot's `start_time` field (which is a string, so it'll need to be parsed):

```
import datetime

# Fetch all snaps
snaps = conn.get_all_snapshots()
# Get UTC of 30-days ago
cutoff = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
# datetime parsing format "2015-09-07T20:12:08.000Z"
DATEFORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
# filter older
old_snaps = [s for s in snaps \
             if datetime.datetime.strptime(s.start_time, DATEFORMAT) < cutoff]
# filter newer
new_snaps = [s for s in snaps \
             if datetime.datetime.strptime(s.start_time, DATEFORMAT) >= cutoff]
```

`old_snaps` will contain the ones from before this month and `new_snaps` will contain the ones from this month.  (I have the feeling you want to delete the old snaps, that's why I included the `old_snaps` line.)

I'm using datetime.strptime() above because it's builtin, but dateutil is more robust if you have it installed.  (See this for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908349/1293152)