# How to get list of all EBS Snapshots "started" before a certain date?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I am writing a Python program to get a list of all the EBS snapshots in our account (owner=self) that were "started" (basically, created) before a certain date, then perform some other actions on that list.

I don't think I can use filters in the get_all_snapshots() function because it only supports equality, not GT/LT operators.  I believe [AWS boto Get Snapshots in Time Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891834/aws-boto-get-snapshots-in-time-period) confirms this.

So I supposed I have to get a list of all of them, then iterate through the list.  However, the boto documentation isn't clear to me (http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.snapshot) exactly what methods/properties are available on the snapshot object.

Any guidance here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get a connection:

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
```

Get your snapshots:

```
snaps = conn.get_all_snapshots(owner="self")
```

Iterate through the list and look at the `start_time` attribute: `snaps[0].start_time`

Use `dir(snaps[0])` to see all available attributes and find other things you need.

Comment: Got it, this is exactly what I ended up doing.  Thanks.