# aws date parser in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

This is the date format of AWS, how can I parse using and separate year day months and so on.

snapshot_time = str(snapshot_name.snapshot_create_time)
snapshot_year = datetime.datetime.strptime(snapshot_time,"%Y-%m-%d-%H").year

Error: ValueError: time data '2014-08-09T04:31:39.870Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d-%H'
I agree with the error, but how to fix it. I think part 09T04 is the problem area

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/ should help

Comment: Got it thanks,
snapshot_time = str(snapshot_name.snapshot_create_time)
snapshot_time = dateutil.parser.parse(snapshot_time)
snapshot_year = snapshot_time.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzutc()).year

Answer (score 0):

```
snapshot_time = str(snapshot_name.snapshot_create_time)
snapshot_time = dateutil.parser.parse(snapshot_time)
snapshot_year = snapshot_time.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzutc()).year
```

Comment: COuld you elaborate a little bit ?