# Python strptime value error

Tags: python

I have a datetime in the format `2015-08-02 07:06:46.022111+00:00`. When I use `strptime()` on this with format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"` I got an error `'ValueError unconverted data remains: +00:00'`. Is there any way to include `+00:00` part to the format string?

Comment: Please show the full code that produced the error. You may get an answer without it but it at least gives people a start. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure it ends with `+00:00`? Does it happen to end with `+0000` instead?

Comment: Seems you are missing the Timezone, `%z`. However you might need to remove the colon there to make it work. edit: or it is as @ozgur assumes.

Comment: I got this datetime from django timezone. now(). It has a colon. I don't see a way to remove the colon.

Comment: Try `t = t[:len(t)-3]+t[len(t)-2:]` (it's called slicing) on your datetime string `t`, that should remove the colon. Then append `%z` to your format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the [`python-dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module. With this module parsing `datetime` is just as simple as that:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('2015-08-02 07:06:46.022111+00:00')
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 2, 7, 6, 46, 22111, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

You can install it with `pip`:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: Yeah, `dateutil` seems to be the preferred way of converting ISO 8601 formatted dates back into `datetime` objects.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing to get rid of the colon and add `%z` to also specify the timezone:

```
import datetime
timestring = '2015-08-02 07:06:46.022111+00:00'
timestring = timestring[:len(timestring)-3]+timestring[len(timestring)-2:]
dtformat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, dtformat)
```

`dt` is then:

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 2, 7, 6, 46, 22111, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```