# strptime pattern for something like 2015-11-21T15:30:00

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I need to parse a datetime object from a give date as a string. The date looks like this: `2015-11-21T15:30:00`

However, the following fails: 
`datetime.strptime("%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M:%S", "2015-11-21T15:30:00")` 
with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data "%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M:%S" does not match format '2015-11-21T15:30:00'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You've put the `T` in quotes - why did you put the `T` in quotes? There are no quotes in the string you're trying to parse.

Comment: Afaik this is required if another character appears in a string date. This should be a correct usage - at least from my other experiences. BTW: Removing the quotes does not solve the problem

Comment: your experiences are wrong in this case (notice that all escape sequences start with `%` and therefore you don't need to escape `T`).

Comment: Your advice does noth work. Or please give me the exact pattern you mean

Comment: You also have the template and the string to parse against it the wrong way around, which is why the *"time data"* is your format and the *"format"* is your time data. I'd strongly recommend reading the docs, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: related: [How do I translate a ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/969285/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format of `strptime` is `(date_string, format)`. So you were doing it the other way around. Plus, you dont need the `'` of the `T`:

```
datetime.strptime("2015-11-21T15:30:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```