# Parse a Date WITHOUT third-party Python modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

How can I parse this date:

```
2016-06-10T00:00:00Z
```

into:

```
Jun 6, 2016
```

Using Python 2.7 without a third-party lib?

I have seen dateparser and datetime, but am not sure the best approach to take.

Comment: 1. Why *"without a  third-party lib"*. 2. Have you tried taking *any* approach? 3. How would you even measure *"best"*.

Comment: 1) because i am on a server environment that is prohibitive to installing modules-ie thet have to be compiled from source instead of PIP install

Comment: 2) I have tried using strptime() but was unsuccesful

Comment: 3) Searches for  the term "best way" on SO return 435,273 results, it is a common expression I guess i picked up from other SO users that usually gets responses with pro/con or specific things to look out for. That is what I was expecting.

Comment: How is `datetime` a "third-party lib"? Who is the third party? It is built into Python and comes with every distribution of it I know of

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the answers in the question marked as a duplicate use third-party modules in their answers.

Comment: I have stated nowhere in this post  that datetime is a third-party lib. I have said that I have tried it and have not been able to make it work, such that there is no useful code to post of my trials.

Comment: not an answer because the tags include python2, but I still drop it here because it's relevant by title alone: python3.7 has https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to study the datetime module capabilities more, but this does what you ask:

```
>>> d = "2016-06-10T00:00:00Z"
>>> d2 = d.split("-")
>>> d2
['2016', '06', '10T00:00:00Z']
>>> m = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June"]
>>> 
>>> result = m[int(d2[1])-1] + " " + d2[2][:2] + ", " + d2[0]
>>> 
'June 10, 2016'
```

Of course put all months in m.  I didn't feel like typing all 12!

Comment: I have further studies datetime and tried solutions in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object that do not use non-native modules and as far as I can tell there is no way to do this using native Python date parsing methods