# Validate an ISO-8601 datetime string in Python?

Tags: python, validation, datetime, iso8601, arrow-python

I want to write a function that takes a string and returns `True` if it is a valid ISO-8601 datetime--precise to microseconds, including a timezone offset--`False` otherwise.

I have found [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-a-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date-in-python/30696682#30696682) that provide different ways of *parsing* datetime strings, but I want to return `True` in the case of ISO-8601 format only. Parsing doesn't help me unless I can get it to throw an error for formats that don't match ISO-8601.

(I am using the nice [arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow) library elsewhere in my code. A solution that uses `arrow` would be welcome.)

---

**EDIT:** It appears that a general solution to "is this string a valid ISO 8601 datetime" does not exist among the common Python datetime packages.

So, to make this question narrower, more concrete and answerable, I will settle for a format string that will validate a datetime string in this form:

```
'2016-12-13T21:20:37.593194+00:00'
```

Currently I am using:

```
format_string = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
datetime.datetime.strptime(my_timestamp, format_string)
```

This gives:

```
ValueError: time data '2016-12-13T21:20:37.593194+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

The problem seems to lie with the colon in the UTC offset (`+00:00`). If I use an offset without a colon (e.g. `'2016-12-13T21:20:37.593194+0000'`), this parses properly as expected. This is apparently because `datetime`'s `%z` token [does not respect the UTC offset form that has a colon](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), only the form without, even though [both are valid per the spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC).

Comment: The format is strict enough that it wouldn't be hard to just validate it the hard way, piecemeal.

Comment: And you've tried... what, exactly?

Comment: Have you looked at the `iso8601` package on PyPI?

Comment: I've updated the text of my question to clarify my requirements. My issue with `iso8601` and other parsers (`arrow`, `dateutil`) is that I want to restrict the acceptable input format, as opposed to allowing any input format that the parser understands.

Comment: This answer to another similar (but not identical) question gives insights into the problem I'm struggling with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date-in-python/30696682#30696682

Comment: It's not that the requirements are unclear, it's that you're not demonstrating any attempt to implement this yourself. What have you tried? What happened?

Answer (score 23):

Recent versions of Python (from 3.7 onwards) have a `fromisoformat()` function in the `datetime` standard library. See: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html

So this will do the trick:

```
from datetime import datetime

def datetime_valid(dt_str):
    try:
        datetime.fromisoformat(dt_str)
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

**Update:**

I learned that Python does not recognize the 'Z'-suffix as valid.
As I wanted to support this in my API, I'm now using (after incorporating Matt's feedback):

```
from datetime import datetime

def datetime_valid(dt_str):
    try:
        datetime.fromisoformat(dt_str.replace('Z', '+00:00'))
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: I think you could just use the `.replace` version since there shouldn't be a `Z` anywhere else in the iso string?

Comment: in my python 3.9 it's now `datetime.date.fromisoformat`

Comment: @Ufos both `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat` and `datetime.date.fromisoformat` functions exist (checked with Python 3.9.7). `date.fromisoformat` expects and returns a date only where `datetime.fromisoformat` takes a full iso8601 string.

Comment: Ah, I see. `from datetime import datetime` got me confused, so I was looking for a top-level method and couldn't find any.

Answer (score 18):

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s07.html

give many variants for validating date and times in ISO8601 format (e.g., 2008-08-30T01:45:36 or 2008-08-30T01:45:36.123Z). The regex for the XML Schema dateTime type is given as:

```
>>> regex = r'^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\.[0-9]+)?(Z|[+-](?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])?$'
```

So in order to validate you could do:

```
import re
match_iso8601 = re.compile(regex).match
def validate_iso8601(str_val):
    try:            
        if match_iso8601( str_val ) is not None:
            return True
    except:
        pass
    return False
```

Some examples:

```
>>> validate_iso8601('2017-01-01')
False

>>> validate_iso8601('2008-08-30T01:45:36.123Z')
True

>>> validate_iso8601('2016-12-13T21:20:37.593194+00:00')
True
```

Comment: Remark, it doesn't check that the date exists.
For example, "2019-02-29T12:00:00+00:00" is not a valid iso date, but your code would say it is OK.

Comment: Your second example is not a valid ISO date. It is a military timezone format. If you put that string in `datetime.fromisoformat()` you will get `ValueError: Invalid isoformat string`.

Comment: That is strange because according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 the "Z" is the time zone designator for the zero UTC offset.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a crude but functional solution (for the narrower question) using `datetime.strptime()`:

```
import datetime

def is_expected_datetime_format(timestamp):
    format_string = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
    try:
        colon = timestamp[-3]
        if not colon == ':':
            raise ValueError()
        colonless_timestamp = timestamp[:-3] + timestamp[-2:]
        datetime.datetime.strptime(colonless_timestamp, format_string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints you've put on the problem, you could easily solve it with a regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{6}[+-]\d\d:\d\d$', '2016-12-13T21:20:37.593194+00:00')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 32), match='2016-12-13T21:20:37.593194+00:00'>
```

If you need to pass *all* variations of ISO 8601 it will be a much more complicated regular expression, but it could still be done. If you also need to validate the numeric ranges, for example verifying that the hour is between 0 and 23, you can put parentheses into the regular expression to create match groups then validate each group.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I wanted to avoid rolling my own date parsing implementation, because others have already done this. I prefer to not reinvent the wheel, and I prefer to use code that has been used and tested by many others, whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]  import dateutil.parser as dp

In [2]: import re
     ...: def validate_iso8601_us(str_val):
     ...:     try:
     ...:         dp.parse(str_val)
     ...:         if re.search('\.\d\d\d\d\d\d',str_val):
     ...:             return True
     ...:     except:
     ...:         pass
     ...:     return False
     ...:

In [3]: validate_iso8601_us('2019/08/15T16:03:5.12345')
Out[3]: False

In [4]: validate_iso8601_us('2019/08/15T16:03:5.123456')
Out[4]: True

In [5]: validate_iso8601_us('2019/08/15T16:03:5.123456+4')
Out[5]: True

In [6]: validate_iso8601_us('woof2019/08/15T16:03:5.123456+4')
Out[6]: False
```