# Convert zulu time string to MST datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

How can I convert this string to MST timezone `datetime` object?

```
>>> type(date_str)
<type 'str'>
>>> date_str
'2017-01-17T20:02:45.767Z'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant string.  There are various [libraries that can convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908349/7311767) this.  But to combine this with a Timezone conversion, you can:

```
import datetime as dt
from pytz import timezone

def convert_my_iso_8601(iso_8601, tz_info):
    assert iso_8601[-1] == 'Z'
    iso_8601 = iso_8601[:-1] + '000'
    iso_8601_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(iso_8601, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    return iso_8601_dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC')).astimezone(tz_info)

my_dt = convert_my_iso_8601('2017-01-17T20:02:45.767Z', timezone('MST'))
```

Comment: Is there a way to take day light savings time into account? the above code doesn't

Comment: Doesn't take DST into account how?  The Z implies the original timestamp is in Zulu.  Thus it does not have DST.  Thus I think the only thing you should need to do for DST is apply a timezone which has one.  I used MST only since you had.  What timezone did you have in mind?

Comment: The input I get is still zulu time, I would like to convert it to MST with DST accounted.

Comment: There at least three different time zones that are abbreviated as MST. http://www.timeandzone.com/zones-abbreviation?hl=en

Comment: Forgive me, now I understand, it's `Mountain Standard (North America)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a **Python 3.9** option, using the standard lib only:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

date_str = '2017-01-17T20:02:45.767Z'

# to datetime, UTC:
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(date_str.replace('Z', '+00:00'))

# to mountain standard time:
dt_mountain = dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo("America/Denver"))

print(dt_mountain.isoformat())
# 2017-01-17T13:02:45.767000-07:00
```

For older versions, a different approach using [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/):

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil

date_str = '2017-01-17T20:02:45.767Z'

# to datetime, UTC:
dt = dateutil.parser.parse(date_str)

# to mountain standard time:
dt_mountain = dt.astimezone(dateutil.tz.gettz("America/Denver"))

print(dt_mountain.isoformat())
# 2017-01-17T13:02:45.767000-07:00
```