# Format Google Calendar Event Date

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-calendar-api, datetime-format

Im working with the Python Google Calendar APi.

The Code:

```
import datetime
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                          maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If run, the output looks like this:

```
2018-12-26T10:00:00+01:00 Event Name
```

That is ISO format from what I know. The problem is that I cannot find a way of formatting that time to something human like "26 December, 10:00".

I've tried alot of things.
I cannot use `.strftime(), .strptime()`nor`dateutil.parser`

The most promising this was doing:
variable = datetime.datetime.strptime(now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime("%B %d, %Y") but then I get this error..

ValueError: time data '2018-12-13T11:56:31.095470Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

I've searched on the internet but I've found just an [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889379/google-calendar-api-datetime-format-python)

Comment: By 'I cannot use .strftime(), .strptime()nordateutil.parser', do you mean you literally can't or you've not been successful using them?

Then you show us a datetime.strptime example.. so I guess it's the latter.

Comment: i've not been successful using them. Error says that "str" doesn't have object ".strftime" nor ".strptime" and so on

Comment: Can you try my answer.. and let me know if it works. Also, can you show us the result of `print(start)` to see what it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do it using `dateutil.parser` and `datetime.datetime.strftime` together.**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as dtparse
from datetime import datetime as dt

start = '2018-12-26T10:00:00+01:00'   # Let's say your start value returns this as 'str'
tmfmt = '%d %B, %H:%M %p'             # Gives you date-time in the format '26 December, 10:00 AM' as you mentioned

# now use the dtparse to read your event start time and dt.strftime to format it
stime = dt.strftime(dtparse(start), format=tmfmt)
```

**Output:**

```
Out[23]: '26 December, 10:00 AM'
```

**Then use the below command to print the event.**

```
print(stime, event['summary'])
```