# Pandas data frame - to_json() to_csv() don't act the same for dates in iso format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting dates from my API in iso format.

When I'm doing:

```
df = DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=file_name, index=False, encoding='utf-8',
          compression='gzip',
          quoting=QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

And I look at the CSV I see for example:

```
lastDeliveryDate
2018-11-21 16:25:53.990000-05:00
```

However,

When I do:

```
df = DataFrame(results)
df.to_json(path_or_buf=file_name, orient="records",compression='gzip', lines=True)
```

I see (other record):

```
"lastDeliveryDate":1543258826689
```

This is a problem.

When I load the data from the CSV to Google BigQuery eveything is fine. The date is parsed correctly.

But when I changed the loading to Json. It doesn't parse the date correctly.

I see the dates in this format:

```
50866-01-09 23:46:40 UTC
```

This occurs because the `to_json()` and `to_csv()` produce different results for dates in `iso_format`

How can I fix this? Must I edit the data frame and convert all my dates columns to regular UTC? how can I do that? and why it's needed for `to_json()` but not `for to_csv()` ?

as explained at [How do I translate an ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-an-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object) Tried to do:

```
df["lastDeliveryDate"] = dateutil.parser.parse(df["lastDeliveryDate"])
```

But it gives:

> TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not Series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Pandas documentation on `to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

> **date_format**: *{None, ‘epoch’, ‘iso’}*
>   Type of date conversion. ‘epoch’ = epoch milliseconds, ‘iso’ = ISO8601. The default depends on the orient. For `orient='table'`, the default is ‘iso’. For all other orients, the default is ‘epoch’.

So, with `orient="records"`, you'll have to set `date_format="iso"` to get a date-time format that can be understood later on:

```
df.to_json(path_or_buf=file_name, orient="records", date_format="iso", 
           compression='gzip', lines=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `dateutil.parser.parse()` is expecting a string as a parameter, but you passed the whole column. Try with the lambda function:

```
df["lastDeliveryDate"] = df["lastDeliveryDate"].apply( lambda row: dateutil.parser.parse(row))
```