# Which method to convert strings in a UTC format into day-month-year string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

I would like to convert two lists of strings into lists with one same time format.

Here are our two lists:

```
# first list: strings with UTC format
firstlist = ['2013-08-16T07:35:01Z','2012-11-17T17:07:49Z','2012-11-09T23:24:13Z']

# second list: strings with day-month-year format
secondlist = ['04-06-2016','31-10-2018','12-04-2019']
```

I would like to convert these two lists and get the same format `year-month-day` for each item:

```
['2013-08-16','2012-11-17','2012-11-09'] # expected for the first list
['2016-06-04','2018-10-31','2019-04-12'] # expected for the second list
```

I tried with just one item per list:

```
import time

time.strptime("2013-08-16T07:35:01Z", "%d %m %y")
time.strptime("04-06-2016", "%d %m %y")
```

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: time data '2013-08-16T07:35:01Z' does not match format '%d %m %y'
```

I found these two documentations: [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) and [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

But I am still really confused. There is probably something wrong with my method, but I struggle to find the right one for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strptime` returns a [`struct_time` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time), given a string to parse. You need to specify the date/time format of the actual input string:

```
import time

# string to time struct
a = time.strptime("2013-08-16T07:35:01Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
b = time.strptime("04-06-2016", "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Then, use `strftime` to format the `struct_time` object into a string:

```
# time struct to formatted string
a_formatted = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', a)
b_formatted = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', b)

print(a_formatted,b_formatted)
```

Output:

```
2013-08-16 2016-06-04
```

Answer (score 2):

This does it

```py
import dateutil.parser

firstlist = list (map (lambda x: str (dateutil.parser.parse (x).date()), firstlist))
secondlist = list (map (lambda x: str (dateutil.parser.parse (x).date()), secondlist))
```

Use `dateutil.parser.parse` to convert to `datetime`.

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-an-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object)

Comment: `[parser.parse(x).date().isoformat() for x in firstlist]` is shorter. `list(map(...` is too verbose in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **dateutil** parser to parse almost any time format.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse


firstlist = ['2013-08-16T07:35:01Z','2012-11-17T17:07:49Z','2012-11-09T23:24:13Z']
secondlist = ['04-06-2016','31-10-2018','12-04-2019']

new_firstlist = [datetime.datetime.strftime(parse(dt), "%Y-%m-%d") for dt in firstlist]
new_secondlist = [datetime.datetime.strftime(parse(dt), "%Y-%m-%d") for dt in secondlist]

print(new_firstlist)
print(new_secondlist)
```