# I need to covert a timestamps from mysql (2019-08-16T10:36:03.562908+00:00) to 06-08-2019

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, datetime

I use orator to store created_at timestamps in my database tables.  When I retrieve this timestamp (job.created_at) it look like this.
2019-08-16T10:36:03.562908+00:00

I need to convert this into 16-08-2019

I have tried datetime.datetime

```
ts = str(job.created_at)
f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, f))
```

This is expecting %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S but is being passed 2019-08-16T10:36:03.562908+00:00 so I get a format does not match error.

I'd forgotten how tricky handling dates in Python is.  Is there an equivalent to php's Carbon package?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to convert the string, try just slicing the data into the format you want:

```py
unformatted_date = '2019-08-16T10:36:03.562908+00:00'
formatted_date = unformatted_date[8:10] + '-' + unformatted_date[5:7] + '-' + unformatted_date[:4]
```

If you want to use a datetime:

```py
import datetime

unformatted_date = '2019-08-16T10:36:03.562908+00:00'
my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-01-04T16:41:24+0200', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
formatted_date = my_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Sources:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/969324/3908572)
- [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)

Comment: Thanks that did it.