# Python datetime.fromisoformat() rejects JavaScript Date/Time string: ValueError: Invalid isoformat string

Tags: python

Why does the following JS date string fail? It's passed from a JS Date object to a Python backend.

```
2021-12-31T05:00:00.000Z


mydate = datetime.fromisoformat(form['expirationDate'])
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2021-12-31T05:00:00.000Z'
```

Comment: Yep, such a shame different programming languages to this day cannot agree on a standard datetime representation, yet still call it "ISO format"

Comment: Note the `Z` format is finally supported in Python 3.11. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat), `date.fromisoformat()` only supports the `YYYY-MM-DD` format .

I believe the easiest way to solve the problem would be to use `dateutil.parser.isoparse()`.

For example:

```
import dateutil.parser
mydate = dateutil.parser.isoparse('2021-12-31T05:00:00.000Z')
print(mydate)
```

will correctly print `2021-12-31 05:00:00+00:00`

If you are bound to using `datetime`, take a look at [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and/or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-an-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object)

EDIT: my bad, I confused datetime with date, sooo.. as others pointed out you could remove the trailing `Z` and call it a day

Answer (score 3):

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat) for `fromisoformat()`,  it seems that 'Z' *(which stands for UTC)* is not recognised as a valid offset. Replacing it with `+00:00` seems to work.

Other time zones would not be an issue as they are already automatically represented with a numerical offset. eg: `+05:30` for IST.

Answer (score 3):

It fails because of the "Z" suffix at the end. If you replace it with "+00:00", you'll be in business.

```
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 24 2021, 12:50:35) 
[GCC 11.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> def fromisoformat(s):
...   return datetime.fromisoformat(s.rstrip("Z") + "+00:00")
... 
>>> fromisoformat("2021-12-31T05:00:00.000Z")
datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 5, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `z` at the end of your string.

```
from datetime import datetime

date = '2021-12-31T05:00:00.000'

t = datetime.fromisoformat(date)
print(t)
```