# Converting string formatted ISO date to Epoch in Python

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

I have a string formatted date `2021-12-14T12:05:51.8031499`
How can I get the Epoch value of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I translate an ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-an-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object)

Comment: Looks like your timestamp has too many microseconds to be valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is your friend, also with 7 digits of fractional seconds:

```py
from dateutil.parser import isoparse

isoparse("2021-12-14T12:05:51.8031499")
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 14, 12, 5, 51, 803149)

isoparse("2021-12-14T12:05:51.8031499").timestamp()
Out[3]: 1639479951.803149
```

Note: given ISO format date/time will result in a [naive datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects), which Python will treat as *local time*, i.e. it will be converted from your machine's local time setting to UTC before Unix time is calculated for `timestamp()` !

Answer (score 2):

Parse date string to datetime object then use [utcfromtimestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) function to return the epoch time from it. Can also call `datetime.fromtimestamp(time, tz=timezone.utc)`.

Note there is one extra digit in the example time. Expected microseconds in Python datetime is 6 digits not 7 (e.g. 803149).

```python
from datetime import datetime, timezone
d = '2021-12-14T12:05:51.803149'

dt = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
print(dt)

# convert datetime to time-zone aware datetime at UTC
# so correct timestamp is returned
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

# Return the time in seconds since the epoch 
seconds_since_epoch = dt.timestamp()
print(seconds_since_epoch)

# convert epoch back to datetime object
d2 = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch)
print(d2)
# this creates a timezone-aware datatime
d3 = datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch, tz=timezone.utc)
print(d3)
```

**Output:**

```
2021-12-14 12:05:51.803149
1639483551.803149
2021-12-14 12:05:51.803149
2021-12-14 12:05:51.803149+00:00
```

Note calling `fromtimestamp()` with tz argument creates a timezone-aware datetime object. Note "+00:00" suffix in output means UTC.