# UTC Timestamp String to UNIX timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am currently working with a given time in the following format

> "2022-03-21T12:14:28.725Z"

I want to compare this time I get from the internet to the local `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` but I can't seem to get the conversion from string to unix timestamp right. Especially with the milliseconds.

I have already tried to use `datetime.fromisoformat('2022-03-21T12:14:28.725Z')` but no luck there.

To better understand my situation I am doing this to check the time off-set between a Server and my local machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
[How do I translate an ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-an-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object)

```
from dateutil import parser

parser.parse('2022-03-21T12:14:28.725Z')
```